# How to map to JSX input fields with a certain flex style conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a form with several fields, but I can't get my head around this one. It seems simple, but most approaches I've taken are messy or didn't work. I'm trying to get the following result:

```html
<div>
  <input />
</div>
<div>
  <input />
  <input />
</div>
```

No matter what I try, these divs always end up on their own line. What am I doing wrong here?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-shirley-4kcbj?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const renderFields = fields =>
  fields.map(({ name }) => (
    <div style={{ display: name !== "fieldA" ? "inline-block" : "" }}>
      <input />
    </div>
  ));

export default function App() {
  const fields = [{ name: "fieldA" }, { name: "fieldB" }, { name: "fieldC" }];
  return renderFields(fields);
}
```

Comment: In your example, all divs are in the same line. I want to conditionally display them inline, like in the codesandbox I linked. I've added a code snippet example in the question, of what the result should look like.